# FFmpeg - The two pass in VP9 generates a empty output file for the first pass

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, vp9

When I try to encode a video file with a two pass in ffmpeg, the output file of the first pass is empty using vp9. Hence I can not proceed with the second part.

Code for the two-pass:

1.pass:

```
ffmpeg -y -s:v 3840x1920 -framerate 30 -i video_framerate_resolution.yuv -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 20
-pass 1 -an -f avi NULL && \
```

2.pass

```
ffmpeg -s:v 3840x1920 -framerate 30 -i video_framerate_resolution.yuv -c:v libvpx-vp9
-pass 2 -b:v 1000K -f avi out.avi
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to generate a file for the first pass. The purpose is simply to send the frames to the encoder so that it can log stats. However, you should skip the muxer.

So, Pass 1

```
ffmpeg -s:v 3840x1920 -framerate 30 -i video_framerate_resolution.yuv -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 1000k -pass 1 -an -f null -
```

Pass 2

```
ffmpeg -s:v 3840x1920 -framerate 30 -i video_framerate_resolution.yuv -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pass 2 -b:v 1000K out.avi
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried your code, but the same yellow message appears again in the first pass: 'Output file is empty, nothing was encoded'. If I ignore it and proceed with the second part a red error message occur: 'Option framerate not found'

Comment: Ah. The first is a warning, not an error. Ignore it. For the second, add `-f rawvideo` before `-i`. If it still doesn't work, paste the full console for pass 2. Add `-report` to log it.